# Save config faild When I configure my iOS 8.0 VPN connection

Tags: objective-c, ios8, vpn

I use Network Extension framework to configure and manage VPN connections. When I running my code ,it will log error message :"Save config faild[(null)]" before  I finish install the config file. I’ve written my code as following:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

self.vpnManager = [NEVPNManager sharedManager];
[_vpnManager loadFromPreferencesWithCompletionHandler:^(NSError * _Nullable error) {
    if (error) {
        NSLog(@"Load config failed [%@]", error.localizedDescription);
        return ;
    }
    // config IPSec protocol
    NEVPNProtocolIKEv2 *p = _vpnManager.protocol;
    if (p) {

    }else{
        p = [[NEVPNProtocolIKEv2 alloc]init];
    }

    p.username = @"qlvpn";
    p.serverAddress = @"my serverAddress";

    // get password persistent reference from keychain


    p.passwordReference = [self searchKeychainCopyMatching:@"kd2014@"];
    // If password doesn't exist in keychain, should create it beforehand.
    if (!p.passwordReference) {
        [self createKeychainValue:@"kd2014@" forIdentifier:@"kd2014@"];
         p.passwordReference = [self searchKeychainCopyMatching:@"kd2014@"];
    }
    p.authenticationMethod = NEVPNIKEAuthenticationMethodSharedSecret;
    p.sharedSecretReference = [self searchKeychainCopyMatching:@"PSK"];
    if (!p.sharedSecretReference) {
        [self createKeychainValue:@"qlvpn_kd2014@" forIdentifier:@"PSK"];
        p.sharedSecretReference = [self searchKeychainCopyMatching:@"PSK"];
    }

    p.localIdentifier = @"qlvpn.client";
    p.remoteIdentifier = @"qlvpn.server";

    p.useExtendedAuthentication = YES;
    p.disconnectOnSleep = NO;
    _vpnManager.protocol = p;
    _vpnManager.localizedDescription = @"IKEv2 Demo";

    [_vpnManager saveToPreferencesWithCompletionHandler:^(NSError * _Nullable error) {
        NSLog(@"Save config faild[%@]",error.localizedDescription);
    }];

}];
```

}

The keyChain method like this:

```
    static NSString * const serviceName = @"qlvpn.vpn_config";

- (NSMutableDictionary *)newSearchDictionary:(NSString *)identifier {
    NSMutableDictionary *searchDictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

    [searchDictionary setObject:(__bridge id)kSecClassGenericPassword forKey:(__bridge id)kSecClass];

    NSData *encodedIdentifier = [identifier dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    [searchDictionary setObject:encodedIdentifier forKey:(__bridge id)kSecAttrGeneric];
    [searchDictionary setObject:encodedIdentifier forKey:(__bridge id)kSecAttrAccount];
    [searchDictionary setObject:serviceName forKey:(__bridge id)kSecAttrService];

    return searchDictionary;
}

- (NSData *)searchKeychainCopyMatching:(NSString *)identifier {
    NSMutableDictionary *searchDictionary = [self newSearchDictionary:identifier];

    // Add search attributes
    [searchDictionary setObject:(__bridge id)kSecMatchLimitOne forKey:(__bridge id)kSecMatchLimit];

    // Add search return types
    // Must be persistent ref !!!!
    [searchDictionary setObject:@YES forKey:(__bridge id)kSecReturnPersistentRef];

    CFTypeRef result = NULL;
    SecItemCopyMatching((__bridge CFDictionaryRef)searchDictionary, &result);

    return (__bridge_transfer NSData *)result;
}

- (BOOL)createKeychainValue:(NSString *)password forIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier {
    NSMutableDictionary *dictionary = [self newSearchDictionary:identifier];

    OSStatus status = SecItemDelete((__bridge CFDictionaryRef)dictionary);

    NSData *passwordData = [password dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    [dictionary setObject:passwordData forKey:(__bridge id)kSecValueData];

    status = SecItemAdd((__bridge CFDictionaryRef)dictionary, NULL);

    if (status == errSecSuccess) {
        return YES;
    }
    return NO;
}
```

So， I really don't know Why i cant save the config..

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't save it unless I called both

```
loadAllFromPreferencesWithCompletionHandler
loadFromPreferencesWithCompletionHandler
```

and only then

```
saveToPreferencesWithCompletionHandler
```